# MediaWiki search in <syntaxhighlight> tag (SyntaxHighlight GeSHi extension)

Tags: syntax-highlighting, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions, geshi

How to enable searching in `<syntaxhighlight>` tag ([SyntaxHighlight GeSHi extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight))? I'm trying to search for `com.android.chrome` in it, but no result found :-(. String is IMHO long enough to be found.

```
<syntaxhighlight lang="java">
supproclist.add("com.whatsapp");
supproclist.add("com.android.chrome");
</syntaxhighlight>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "enable searching"? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @Florian I updated question to be more specific.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do anything special; everything within `<syntaxhighlight>` tags is already included in the normal site-wide [search system](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Searching) (based on MySQL search).

**Edit:** You definitely should be getting a match on `com.android.chrome`. Is this on a public wiki? Can you provide a link?

You won't get a result when searching for `com.android` however, because the search system only finds *whole words*, and the dot is considered part of the word. This is quite separate from, and not changed by, the SyntaxHightlight extension.